# How to add one more channel IDs so that bot will react on more channels?

Tags: python, reactjs, bots, discord, message

I am completly new in coding and found this code on YouTube:

```
import discord
from discord.ext        import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("welcome_msg")

async def react(message):
    custom_emojis = [
    "<:yesvote:683728539794669634>"
    ]
    guild_emoji_names = [str(guild_emoji) for guild_emoji in message.guild.emojis]
    for emoji in custom_emojis:
        if emoji in guild_emoji_names:
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 683418798950187079:
        await react(message)


bot.run("token")
```

I tried to edit it like:

`async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 683418798950187079 or 690608570936459375:
        await react(message)`

... and many more but nothing works and bot either reacts to messages in all channels or doesn't react in any. 
Could anyone help me how to solve it?

Comment: Forgot to add. This bot has to react to every message posted on a selected channel.

Comment: you might want to remove that token or whatever it is from your post.